# check whether an Iframe contains a youtube link in its source or not?

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

I currently using plain javascript trying to find the iframes that contains a youtube link.

but for some reason I am getting null, eventhough I know for certain there is one iframe that contains a youtube video.

```
var allIframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var selectedIframe of allIframes)
    if (selectedIframe.src.match(/\byoutube[a-zA-Z]*/g))
    {

    }
//Returns null once - not the number of iframes?
```

I would expect the if statment only to continue if an iframe with the word youtube was matched...?

https://jsfiddle.net/v4r187dt/

Comment: "Returns null once - not the number of iframes?" — You haven't written anything to count the number of matches, and what you've presented isn't a function so it won't return anything. Maybe you should provide a real [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
var getUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").src;
var s = getUrl.includes("youtube");//or anything you want..
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s;//this will return true or false in the element which have this class.
```

and if you have multiple frames:

```
for(i=0; i< getUrl.length; i++){
    window.prompt("output", getUrl[i].src);
}
```